# Character limit of field machine name?

Tags: entities

Is the machine name of a Drupal 7 field limited to 32 characters (including `field_`)? When I'm creating a new field, the UI seems to cut me off there, but I wonder if this can be circumvented.

I'm using prefixes to map certain fields to others, and the fact that my prefixed fields are getting cut off is going to make my matching logic slightly more complex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes the length of the field name is hard-coded to 32 characters. It's most likely because the maximum length for a table name in MySQL is 64 characters, and the field API creates tables with names like `field_revision_field_name`. I imagine the core developers were erring on the side of caution.

It looks like you could squeeze an extra 17 characters out of the field name (`64 - 32 - len('field_revision_')`), but to do that you'll need to alter the `field_config` and `field_config_instance` tables in the database to increase the length of the `field_name` column (I guess to 49 characters).

I would imagine you'll also need to hook into the field UI forms to increase the `#maxlength` of appropriate text fields.

It might be easier to re-think your matching logic :)

Comment: Sounds like not worth doing -- even if I got around it, I'd worry about running into bits of drupal core that are assuming a 32 character field name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late in here, but you may be interested to know that we came across this limit too and I created a module to strip the field_ prefix off all fields created in the Field UI.

https://www.drupal.org/project/field_name_prefix_remove

We've used this on various sites in a variety of circumstances with success.

Although this doesn't directly help you with your original question about the field length limit, it should go some way to give you an additional 6 characters to play with.